# How to switch back and forth between pulseaudio+alsa and alsa only?

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I prefer using alsa only while I make screencast and do skype. Other times, I use pulseaudio/alsa. Is there a quick and easy way to switch between these two states on Ubuntu 12.04 desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use "pasuspender", which tells system to temprarily suspend PulseAudio. Starting your program with it will stop PulseAudio for the period you applications runs, then it will resume PulseAudio operation.

```
pasuspender -- skype
```

Many times it has been said that removing PulseAudio is a bad idea and an unnecessary one. The above should work much better.

General usage of pasuspender:

```
pasuspender [options] -- PROGRAM [ARGUMENTS ...]
```

Comment: If this works then Bingo!!! That's exactly what I want. This means that I can use skype without pulseaudio at the same time use vlc with pulseaudio. Amazing solution. Ofcourse, I did not want to get rid of pulseaudio.

Comment: Uhm not exactly. :) Once you call pasuspender, PA stops working for all applications, so you won't be able to use VLC with PA _at the same time_. Skype will have to exit before you can use VLC with PA. You can however use VLC without PA at the same time.

Comment: Oh Okay, still this does what I want.